# Getting attributes from GMail - OpenID Authentication

Tags: openid, openid-provider

I'm utilizing LightOpenID and I'm trying to get attributes for this gmail authentication but it doesn't appear to return anything on my personal account and I get no errors.  I'm very new to OpenID and was hoping someone could help me out who's done this before.

I'm specifying the fields on `validate()` and returning them with `process()`

I'm using the OpenID URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

```
    public function show () {
        if ($this->site->tru->post->isRequest() || !$this->site->tru->get->isEmpty('openid_mode')) {
            require_once $this->site->tru->config->get('root.path').'/lib/php/openid.php';
            $this->lightOpenId = new LightOpenID;
            if ($this->validate() || $this->lightOpenId->validate()) {
                $this->process();
            }
        }

        $this->site->addCss('account/login.css');

        $this->site->addJs('account/login.js');

        echo $this->site->tru->display->getTemplate('/site/account/login.tpl');
    }

    public function process () {
        if ($this->lightOpenId->validate()) {
            echo '<pre>'.print_r($this->lightOpenId).'
'.print_r($this->lightOpenId->getAttributes()).'</pre>';
        }
    }

    public function validate () {
        if (!$this->site->tru->post->isEmpty('openid_url')) {
            $this->lightOpenId->identity = $this->site->tru->post->get('openid_url');
            $this->lightOpenId->optional = array('contact/email', 'namePerson', 'contact/postalCode/home', 'contact/country/home');

            header('Location: '.$this->lightOpenId->authUrl());
        }

        return count($this->error) == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google answers only to the required parameters, completely ignoring the optional ones.

Also, it can return only following attributes:

```
contact/country/home
contact/email
namePerson/first
namePerson/last
pref/language
```

So `namePerson` and `contact/postalCode/home` won't work.

The above information are specific to Google, and completely unrelated to LightOpenID itself.

As for the library, I'd advise against calling $lightOpenId->validate() twice. Each time you call it, it sends a request to the provider that might reject the second request.

Comment: @Webnet: Indeed, it seems that it doesn't work. My information was based on [Google Federated Login](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) page, so I've assumed that information there would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/';

// use the following line to obtain the required details. These are the only details that google mail provides. This is for lightopenid.
$openid->required = array('namePerson/friendly', 'contact/email' , 'contact/country/home', 'namePerson/first', 'pref/language', 'namePerson/last'); 

header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
```